# Cocoapods optimization level for schemes

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Looking at the project file for Cocoapods `Pods.xcodeproj` it looks like every single scheme for every library (except for `Debug` scheme) has an optimization level of `Fastest, Smallest`.

Is there a quick and easy way to change the `Podfile` or some other configuration of Cocoapods so that the optimization level is `None` for specific schemes when I use `pod install`?

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I use post_install hook in Podfile. Like this:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if config.name.include?("Debug")
            config.build_settings['GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '0'
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '-Onone'
        end
    end
end
```

**EDIT**
`GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL` is ignored for Swift Pods. If you're using Swift Pods you also need to set `SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL`.

Comment: Had to include `if config.name.include?("Localhost")` as well.

Comment: actually it should be `config.build_settings['SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '-Onone'` for the swift setting

Comment: There really is no need for this - IMHO, it is a much cleaner solution to use the `project` keyword in your Podfile and then define which Schemes are debug. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#project "Using custom build configurations".

Comment: How can I do that only for specific pods, and not for all of them?

Answer (score 14):

To anybody seeing this using cocoapods 0.38.0 or later:

Use "pods_project" instead of "project"

The previous answers use the word "project" (installer.project.build_configurations.each)

Project was deprecated and replaced with pods_project.
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3747

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    if config.name.include?("Debug")
      config.build_settings['GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '0'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you also want the DEBUG macro added for debugging with assertions enabled, you can use the following script:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    if config.name.include?("Debug")
      # Set optimization level for project
      config.build_settings['GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '0'

      # Add DEBUG to custom configurations containing 'Debug'
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
      if !config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'].include? 'DEBUG=1'
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << 'DEBUG=1'
      end
    end
  end

  installer.project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if config.name.include?("Debug")
          # Set optimization level for target
          config.build_settings['GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '0'

          # Add DEBUG to custom configurations containing 'Debug'
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
          if !config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'].include? 'DEBUG=1'
            config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << 'DEBUG=1'
          end

          # Enable assertions for target
          config.build_settings['ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS'] = 'YES'

          config.build_settings['OTHER_CFLAGS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
          if config.build_settings['OTHER_CFLAGS'].include? '-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1'
            config.build_settings['OTHER_CFLAGS'].delete('-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1')
          end
        end
      end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `post_install` you can add following line to Podfile:

`project 'ProjectName', 'DebugConfigurationName' => :debug`

Comment: That works for a single configuration, but what's the syntax when you want multiple configurations to behave as debug?

Comment: I finally have an answer and it's pretty simple. First, this is the official guide page for that: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#project and second, you can list different schemes repeating `:debug` and `:release` if you want so, for example: project 'ProjectName', 'FirstDebugName' => :debug, 'SecondDebugName' => :debug, 'FirstReleaseName' => :release, 'SecondReleaseName' => :release