# Xcode 10.2 hangs during Archive on arbitrary Task

Tags: build, archive, xcode10.1, xcode10.2

This question has been asked before with prior Xcode versions:

Their solutions were:

- Remove armv7 from Valid architectures
- Change debug information format to DWARF instead of DWARF with dSYM File

I have tried all of these but the archiving still gets stuck at a particular task, always the same task number.

I have looked into the report navigator, and their are issues. But just warnings. There is one error "FontAwesome" build target, which doesn't say much. But the app use to build with version 10.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those that come across this issue, it was because of FontAwesome. I had installed it via CocoaPods. Not sure what the issue was, but I manually installed it into the project and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Definitely appears to be an issue with FontAwesome.swift. I too had this issue and have been able to successfully build my project after removing the Pod and Manually installing it.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue with HTMLString

Comment: Though it just appears to be hanging, but archiving continues after a very long time...

Comment: I just found out, that removing armv7 from valid architectures solves this issue in my case, but I had to remove it from my projects target AND from the pods target.

Comment: I left it for like 30 mins but it didn't move, and honestly I didn't have the luxury to wait longer. I also tried removing armv7 but that didn't work either.

Comment: In my case it took more than and hour on a very fast Mac. Of course I understand that it's not acceptable to wait that long for a build. Just wanted to note it. Though we probably don't have the same issue anyway...

Comment: I have the same issue, what helped me is to set Compilation Mode to Incremental for Release builds. However, this just workarounds the problem, I have no idea what is the root of it.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. I had to delete FontAwesome from my app. I couldn't make it archive by doing what you suggested but you gave me a clue to figure out what was going on.

Comment: Manually installing FontAwesome.Swift and removing from Cocoapods fixed it for me as well on Xcode 10.2.1

Comment: For me also, only the compilation of FontAwesome.swift takes unexpectedly long. About 400 seconds, ~380 for `armv7` and ~20 for `arm64`, while a normal debug build usually takes about 20 seconds, 10 seconds for each architecture. I guess it‘s because the enormous size of `Enum.swift` where all icon character codes reside.

Comment: This is now fixed in FontAwesome Swift and has been released for v1.8.0 - https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift/pull/213

Answer (score 5):

I was able to work around this by EITHER changing my Optimization Level in Release to "No Optimization" OR by changing Compilation Mode from "Whole Module" to "Incremental".

Comment: In my case the problem appeared only during builds via command line (`xcodebuild` / fastlane). The build process was hanging on `IGListKit` (`IGListAdapter+DebugDescription.m`, `IGListAdapter+UICollectionView.m`) for  ~1-1.5 hours and sometimes on `HTMLString` too. Disabling optimization for my targets AND [cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22373328/1364257) returned build times to normal level. Thank you very much!

Comment: I had to disable BOTH to make it work. This however enables `assert()` calls in production builds due to no optimization :(. I would think Apple would hotfix this, as the Swift compiler is already updated with a fix for this: https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/23931

Answer (score 0):

Upload using Xcode 10.1 instead of Xcode 10.2.